# Override Chrome Storage API using Proxy object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, proxy, es6-proxy

How can I override `chrome.storage.local.get` in order to log the value of the storage key when the Chrome Storage API is called using JavaScript Proxy

Here is what I tried:

```
const api = chrome.storage.local;
const { set } = api; 
api.set = new Proxy(api.set, {
    apply: (target, thisArg, argumentsList) => {
        console.log(argumentsList[0]);
        return target(argumentsList[0]);
    }
});
```

I get `Illegal invocation: Function must be called on an object of type StorageArea` error when `target(argumentsList[0])` gets called

Comment: Use `apply:` trap instead of `get:`, see the documentation for the exact parameters.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've edited my code to use ```apply:``` & I get the above error. Could you pls have a look

Comment: `return target.apply(thisArg, argumentsList);`